# Designing an async API in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, future, api-design, promise

(Note: this question is strictly about the *design* of the API, not about how to implement it; i.e. I only care about what the client of my API sees here, not what I have to do to make it work.)

In simple terms: I want to know the established pattern - if any - for [explicit futures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) (aka promises, aka deferreds, aka tasks - names vary depending on the framework) in Python. Following is a more detailed description.

Consider a simple Python API like this:

```
def read_line():
   ...
s = read_line()
print(s)
```

This is a syncronous version - it will block if a line is not available yet. Suppose, now, that I want to provide a corresponding asynchronous (non-blocking) version that allows to register a callback to be invoked once the operation completes. E.g. a simple version could look like this:

```
def read_line_async(callback):
   ...
read_line_async(lambda s: print(s))
```

Now, in other languages and frameworks, there are often existing mandated or at least well-established patterns for such APIs. For example, in .NET prior to version 4, one would typically provide a pair of `BeginReadLine`/`EndReadLine` methods, and use the stock `IAsyncResult` interface to register callbacks and pass the resulting values. In .NET 4+, one uses `System.Threading.Tasks`, so as to enable all task combining operators (`WhenAll` etc), and to hook up into C# 5.0 `async` feature.

For another example, in JavaScript, there's nothing to cover this in the standard library, but jQuery has popularized the "deferred promise" interface that is now [separately specified](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A). So if I were to write async `readLine` in JS, I would name it `readLineAsync`, and implement `then` method on the returned value.

What, if any, is the established pattern in Python land? Looking through the standard library, I see several modules offering asynchronous APIs, but no consistent pattern between them, and nothing like a standardized protocol for "tasks" or "promises". Perhaps there is some pattern that can be derived from popular third-party libraries?

I've also seen the (oft-mentioned in this context) [Deferred](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.internet.defer.Deferred.html) class in Twisted, but it seems to be overengineered for a general-purpose promise API, and rather adapted to the specific needs of this library. It doesn't look like something that I could easily clone an interface for (without taking a dependency on them) such that our promises would interoperate well if the client uses both libraries together in his application. Is there any other popular library or framework that has an explicitly designed API for this, that I could copy (and interoperate with) without taking a direct dependency?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so I have found [PEP-3148](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3148/), which does have a `Future` class. I cannot quite use it as is, so far as I can see, because proper instances are only created by `Executor`, and that is a class to convert existing synchronous APIs to asynchrony by e.g. moving the synchronous call to a background thread. However, I can replicate exactly the methods provided by `Future` objects - they match very closely what I would expect, i.e. the ability to (blocking) query for result, cancel, and add a callback.

Does this sound like a reasonable approach? Should it, perhaps, be accompanied with a proposal to add an abstract base class for the generic "future" concept to Python standard library, just like Python collections have their [ABCs](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections-abstract-base-classes).

Comment: After further searching, I have found this thread - http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2010-September/008054.html - where Guido confirms that `concurrent.futures.Future` is the right choice.

Comment: `concurrent.futures` has been backported from 3.2 to 2.6+ https://code.google.com/p/pythonfutures/

Answer (score 1):

Read the various "server" libraries for hints.

A good example is [BaseHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html)

Specifically, the [HTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/library/basehttpserver.html#BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer) class definition shows how a "handler class" is provided.

Each request instantiates an instance of the handler class.  That object then handles the request.

If you want to write "asynchronous I/O" with a "callback", you'd provide a `ReadHandler` class to your reader.

```
class AsyncReadHandler( object ):
    def input( self, line, server ):
        print( line )

read_line_async( AsyncReadHandler )
```

Something like that would follow some established design patterns.

Comment: Do other standard async libraries follow the same pattern (i.e. can you easily combine their promise objects in a generic way)? What about inline continuations, i.e. lambdas or local functions? requiring a client to define a class just to provide a single callback sounds rather overkill.

Comment: @Pavel Minaev: Yes.  Probably Not.  Nothing.  "define a class just to provide a single callback sounds rather overkill".  False.   A "callback" can be a rather complex event.  Also, it handles threading and multiprocessing in a better way than a single function.  You asked  about "established pattern".  This is the pattern.  Your follow-up questions are way, way beyond your basic question asking for an established pattern.  If you don't like the established pattern, that's kind of irrelevant, isn't it?

Comment: So as to be more specific and to the point: what I'm looking for is a stock pattern for explicit futures (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) in Python. Not generic callbacks, and not generic reactor pattern, but specifically futures. Question edited accordingly; hope it helps.

Comment: @Pavel Minaev:  It doesn't help.  The established pattern is still a class.  What more do you want?  A different "established" pattern?  The code is the code.  The library is the library.  If your comment is that you object to the established pattern, I'm sorry.  It's still the established pattern.  If you want a different established pattern, please remove the entire "established pattern" part of your question and focus on ONLY the wikipedia article and nothing else.

Comment: You have shown the established pattern for (e.g. server) response handlers. I'm not looking for an established pattern for response handlers. Indeed, even Python designers agree that these two things are different, which is why http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3148/ now exists. Have a look at it to see what I mean.

Comment: The question says: "What, if any, is the established pattern in Python land".  The comment says "I'm not looking for an established pattern for response handlers".  So I'm really lost.  Asynchronous processing in a server is asynchronous processing.  Period.  That's the established pattern.  I guess you don't like the pattern.  If you don't like the pattern, then please close the question as argumentative or not constructive.

Comment: I have already edited the question to say that I'm looking for "established pattern for _futures_ in Python". There are various forms of asynchronous processing, and they cannot all be reasonably covered by a single pattern. What you demonstrated is a pattern that covers a case where a single "process event" handler is registered that handles _multiple_ incoming requests. What I'm looking for is a case where a single "operation complete" (aka continuation) handler is registered that is called _once_ when the associated operation finishes. These two are completely different things.

Comment: Also, your assertion that this _is_ the pattern for such things in Python lacks any substantial evidence. You've referenced `BaseHTTPServer` class, the relevance of which in the context of the question is dubious. I've referenced PEP-3148 in response (note, this is a part of Python as of 3.2) which shows a completely different thing. The latter alone is enough to demonstrate that pattern you're pushing for is not "established", even assuming it applies here at all. So, sorry, but I'm not accepting this as an answer - it's just not helpful - nor the claim that question is "argumentative".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3108/discussion-between-pavel-minaev-and-s-lott)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [decorators](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808) yet?

```
from threading import Thread

def addCallback(function):
    def result(parameters,callback):
        # Run the function.
        result = function(parameters)
        # Run the callback asynchronously.
        Thread(target=callback).start()
        # Run the callback synchronously.
        #callback()
        # Return the value of the function.
        return result
    return result

@ addCallback
def echo(value):
    print value

def callback():
    print 'Callback'

echo('Hello World!',callback)
```

Comment: To reiterate: I'm not looking at implementation techniques at the moment. What I want is feedback on API design - simply put, what is the best, most "Pythonic" way to supply a continuation callback (and possibly other related information, like blocking result and cancelation request objects).

Comment: In that case yes, decorators are what you're looking for. They are by far the most elegant way to graft callback like functionality onto existing functions.

Comment: I'm not looking to graft callback functionality onto existing functions. I'm writing my own functions which are already inherently asynchronous (i.e. I'm handling asynchrony in some less wasteful way than just spinning a synchronous operation up on a background thread and waiting for it to complete), and I want to know how to properly expose that to the clients of my API.